# What is the difference between ":" and "=" in Swift?

Tags: swift

Ive searched for the answer to this for a while and can't seem to find it.

But for example, what is the difference here:

```
var this: that
var this = that
```

Thanks

Comment: It's all in [the basic introduction to Swift](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), see for example the section about "Type Annotations"

Comment: You should check out [The Swift Programming Language](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l). This is covered in the very beginning of the book.

Answer (score 3):

```
var this: That
```

declares a mutable variable of type That.

```
var this = that
```

declares a mutable variabel and assigns an instance of `That` to it. The type (`That`) is inferred in this case.

A more belt and braces method of declaring it:

```
var this: That = that
```

But usually type inference is enough.

Answer (score 1):

`:` force assigns a constant/variable a type, whereas `=` assigns it a value

example of `:`:

```
let str: String = ""
```

example of `=`:

```
let str = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

":" refers to defining the type of the variable

"=" refers to assigning a value to that variable

e.g.

var myString: String (declares a variable of type String)

var myString = "example text" (declares a variable who's type is implicitly determined to be String and assigns the value "example text" to it)

var myString: Int = "example text" (Syntax error. Defined a variable of type Int and tried to assign a String to that value)