# Swift Protocol Where Constraint with == vs :

Tags: ios, protocols, swift4

I have Following Code (please ignore spell mistakes :))

```
protocol Vehical {
    var wheelsCount:Int {get}
}

protocol LightVehical:Vehical {
    func tankWithPetrol (liters:Int)
}

protocol HeavyVehical:Vehical {
    func tankWithDisel(liters:Int)
}

protocol OwnsVehical {
    associatedtype VechicalType = Vehical
    var vehical:VechicalType {get}
}

// Here I have == for constraint  
extension OwnsVehical where VechicalType == HeavyVehical {
    func fillTankWithDisel() {

    }
}
 // Light Vehicle
struct VolVOV90 : LightVehical {

    var wheelsCount: Int = 4

    func tankWithPetrol(liters: Int) {

    }
}
     // Heavy Vehicle

struct Van : HeavyVehical {
    func tankWithDisel(liters: Int) {

    }

    var wheelsCount: Int = 6


}

struct PersonWithHeavyVehical:OwnsVehical {
    typealias VechicalType = Van
    let vehical = Van()
}
```

Now when I tried

```
let personWithHeavyV = PersonWithHeavyVehical()
personWithHeavyV.fillTankWithDisel() // It is not compiling with ==
```

If I change

```
extension OwnsVehical where VechicalType == HeavyVehical
```

With

```
extension OwnsVehical where VechicalType : HeavyVehical
```

Code Compiles successfully I didn't find the diff between == And : Anyone can help me to understand it  Thanks in advance

Comment: `==` means _exactly-that_, `:` means _a-kind-of-that_ in this context.

Comment: @holex EXAMPLE :  `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Int`  is allow to access define property for Int array and `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : FloatingPoint` allow to access all the property / method of array which has floating point

Comment: @holex That mean all  classes can be initialised needs to be constraint with == and protocols can be initialised (can be confirmed only by some struct / class) can be constrained with : ?

Comment: briefly, yes, that is pretty much correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

`extension OwnsVehical where VechicalType == HeavyVehical`

you're telling the compiler that the `VechicalType` **must be** a HeavyVehical type. This means that the method `fillTankWithDisel` will only be available to `OwnsVehical` whose `VechicalType` is a `HeavyVehical`. 
That's why you can't call `fillTankWithDisel` on `personWithHeavyV` because `personWithHeavyV` is not a `HeavyVehical`, it's a `Van`.

When you do:

`extension OwnsVehical where VechicalType : HeavyVehical`

you're telling the compiler that the `VechicalType` **conforms** with the `HeavyVehical` protocol, thus you're allowed to call `personWithHeavyV.fillTankWithDisel` because `personWithHeavyV`, by conforming to `OwnsVehical`, with no further restriction, can call `fillTankWithDisel`.

If you want `personWithHeavyV.fillTankWithDisel()` to compile you'd have to change your implementation of the struct PersonWithHeavyVehical to the following:

`struct PersonWithHeavyVehical: OwnsVehical {
    typealias VechicalType = HeavyVehical
    let vehical = Van()
}`

now you have a `personWithHeavyV` whose VechicalType is a `HeavyVehical` thus allowing you to call the desired method.

Answer (score 0):

1. `==` Operator

   `==` Operator checks if their instance values are equal, `"equal to"`
    //so here you are comparing `VechicalType == HeavyVehical` which return `false`
2. `:` Operator

   `:` refers to defining the type of the variable
   for that you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735790/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-swift)

Comment: Here `Van` is a `HeavyVehical` on line  `typealias VechicalType = Van`  on `OwnsVehical` So it should allow to access `fillTankWithDisel`

Comment: how is your answer related to OP's question, exactly?